# Need suggestions for mining an attribute in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

We have an attribute 'Size' in Magento 1.

It has lots of different types of values in it. For example:

2.64 lbs. ,
2.5 OZ  ,
20 Strips ,
200 Tablets ,
21 Packs  ,
22 Oz - Box of 12 ,
230 Grams ,
237 ml ,
250 Capsules ,
25 Servings ,
3 in 1 Pack ,
30 Caplets ,
etc..

So there is just one attribute combined with another attribute for configurable products.

Now we need to provide filters in product listing page with size attribute but because of different types of values we can't effectively use it for filters.

So we basically need to mine all the values and may need to create different size attributes for different types.

And we have lot of products so question is how to replace newly created attribute with the existing one with making sure the existing products will not break.

any suggestions are most welcome..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is just make an attribute for each type of size and only fill in the one that is related to it. Or you can create 2 different attributes programmaticly. One to define the amount and another to define if this is Tablets or OZ or ...

Next you disable those attributes to be used in a filter.

Then you need to have a custom layered navigation (filter) where you add that attribute and you can have the 2 attributes combined.

Depending on what you want.

Since you have a lot of product you can also create a module where it splits the value of the attribute that you already have in a mass action. So you do not need to fill them all in again but you can use the data that you already have.
In your function of the mass action you can define the attribute that holds the sizes that you have now. You can split the numbers of the other things and saves those 2 new variables in the corresponding new attributes to be used in your new layered navigation.

It involves a lot of custom work but if you have so many products you should also have the resources to have a developer that can make this for you like we do for our customers.

Since this is a request for an idea an not for the code this is all that i can offer. If you have certain questions about how to do this or if your have any problems with some of the aspects i suggest making a new question with some code examples how you want to implement this.